# How can I speed up this SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a piece of code in an ASP.NET application that builds a SQL query from a list of parameters. The number of parameters can vary, so various criteria can be added to this query.  The database is Microsoft SQL Server 2008.

All the AND and OR's are generated programmatically.

The query took more than 3 seconds to execute, but after some profiling and indexes it runs less than a second. Still I think the query itself can be optimized. I've looked at execution plans, but that doesn't mean much to me - not being a SQL guru.

I wonder if the query can be done in a more intelligent fashion - I haven't been able to figure it out. Here's an example of the query:

```
 SELECT [id], [WorkTitle], [CreateDate], [UpdateDate], [Writer], [ValidFrom], 

[ValidTo], [Text] 
 FROM dbo.Texts T  
 WHERE Category_id = 3 AND '2012-11-06' BETWEEN ValidFrom AND ValidTo  
 AND (EXISTS (SELECT 'X' FROM dbo.Criteria_List CL WHERE T.id = CL.Text_id   AND CL.Criteria_id = 1 AND CL.Value = '95068')       
    OR NOT EXISTS (SELECT 'X' FROM dbo.Criteria_List CL WHERE T.id = CL.Text_id AND CL.Criteria_id = 1))  

 AND (EXISTS (SELECT 'X' FROM dbo.Criteria_List CL WHERE T.id = CL.Text_id   AND CL.Criteria_id = 2 AND CL.Value = 'C')       
    OR NOT EXISTS (SELECT 'X' FROM dbo.Criteria_List CL WHERE T.id = CL.Text_id AND CL.Criteria_id = 2))  

 AND (EXISTS (SELECT 'X' FROM dbo.Criteria_List CL WHERE T.id = CL.Text_id   AND CL.Criteria_id = 3 AND CL.Value = 'HEL')       
    OR NOT EXISTS (SELECT 'X' FROM dbo.Criteria_List CL WHERE T.id = CL.Text_id AND CL.Criteria_id = 3))  

 AND (EXISTS (SELECT 'X' FROM dbo.Criteria_List CL WHERE T.id = CL.Text_id   AND CL.Criteria_id = 4 AND CL.Value = 'CC')      
    OR NOT EXISTS (SELECT 'X' FROM dbo.Criteria_List CL WHERE T.id = CL.Text_id AND CL.Criteria_id = 4))  

 AND (EXISTS (SELECT 'X' FROM dbo.Criteria_List CL WHERE T.id = CL.Text_id   AND CL.Criteria_id = 5 AND CL.Value = NULL)     
    OR NOT EXISTS (SELECT 'X' FROM dbo.Criteria_List CL WHERE T.id = CL.Text_id AND CL.Criteria_id = 5))  

 AND (EXISTS (SELECT 'X' FROM dbo.Criteria_List CL WHERE T.id = CL.Text_id   AND CL.Criteria_id = 7 AND CL.Value = '321')      
    OR NOT EXISTS (SELECT 'X' FROM dbo.Criteria_List CL WHERE T.id = CL.Text_id AND CL.Criteria_id = 7))  

 AND (EXISTS (SELECT 'X' FROM dbo.Criteria_List CL WHERE T.id = CL.Text_id   AND CL.Criteria_id = 9 AND CL.Value = 'DK7778')    
    OR NOT EXISTS (SELECT 'X' FROM dbo.Criteria_List CL WHERE T.id = CL.Text_id AND CL.Criteria_id = 9))  

 AND (EXISTS (SELECT 'X' FROM dbo.Criteria_List CL WHERE T.id = CL.Text_id   AND CL.Criteria_id = 10 AND CL.Value = 'TFS')   
    OR NOT EXISTS (SELECT 'X' FROM dbo.Criteria_List CL WHERE T.id = CL.Text_id AND CL.Criteria_id = 10)) 

 AND (EXISTS (SELECT 'X' FROM dbo.Criteria_List CL WHERE T.id = CL.Text_id   AND CL.Criteria_id = 11 AND CL.Value = 'TMP')   
    OR NOT EXISTS (SELECT 'X' FROM dbo.Criteria_List CL WHERE T.id = CL.Text_id AND CL.Criteria_id = 11)) 

 AND (EXISTS (SELECT 'X' FROM dbo.Criteria_List CL WHERE T.id = CL.Text_id   AND CL.Criteria_id = 13 AND CL.Value = 'OY-VKB')   
    OR NOT EXISTS (SELECT 'X' FROM dbo.Criteria_List CL WHERE T.id = CL.Text_id AND CL.Criteria_id = 13))
```

Any tips and tricks are appreciated.

Cheers
Jens

Comment: Is there an index on the table `CL`?

Comment: Yes I used Database Tuning Advisor to add indexes to all tables.

Comment: What indexes do you have exactly? Can you add the tables definitions, too (`CREATE TABLE ...`) for both tables?

Comment: Well I could, but I think that's beside the point. I'm thinking a redesign of the query would help, but I am not sure how to go about it. I've tried with inner and outer joins but could not made it work.

Comment: And the `CL.Value = NULL` should be replaced with `CL.Value IS NULL`

Comment: It could be rewritten with 10 `LEFT` joins but I don't think it would be more efficient.

Comment: Have you tried rewriting the CL.Criteria_id AND CL.Value pairs into a table? I think you could then left join on that, and simplify your WHERE clause. This is a pivot and much as I love them I don't have time to rewrite it right now, I'm sorry!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- For table `Texts` I'd add an index on `(Category_id, ValidFrom) INCLUDE (ValidTo)`, if there isn't one. (If you already have indexes on either `(Category_id, ValidFrom, ValidTo)` or on `(Category_id, ValidFrom)`, they may be quite good too.
- For the `Criteria_List` table an index on `(Text_id, Criteria_id, Value)` would probably be enough for the optimizer to produce a good execution plan.

  The second option (or maybe even better, you'd have to test the execution plans and running times with your tables sizes and distributions) would be two indexes, one on `(Criteria_id, Text_id)` and one on `(Criteria_id, Value, Text_id)`.

---

You could rewrite the 10 conditions like this - but the indexing should be taken care anyway:

```
 WHERE Category_id = 3 AND '2012-11-06' BETWEEN ValidFrom AND ValidTo  
 AND NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 'X' FROM dbo.Criteria_List CL 
                  WHERE T.id = CL.Text_id AND CL.Criteria_id = 1 
                    AND (CL.Value <> '95068' OR CL.Value IS NULL)
                ) 
 AND NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 'X' FROM dbo.Criteria_List CL 
                  WHERE T.id = CL.Text_id AND CL.Criteria_id = 2 
                    AND (CL.Value <> 'C' OR CL.Value IS NULL)
                ) 
 ...
 AND NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 'X' FROM dbo.Criteria_List CL 
                  WHERE T.id = CL.Text_id AND CL.Criteria_id = 5 
                    AND (CL.Value IS NOT NULL)
                ) 
 ...
```

Answer (score 0):

One thing I would suggest is a change to your database design so that you can identify the CriteriaList.value records rather than listing them as you have. That'll make your query more flexible and means that you should be able to get rid of all or most of those exists/not exists and presumably speed up your query.